# Personalized actions on local notifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

Ive been searching for this information for a day now.

I made a custom notification with some interactive buttons and 2 action buttons (send and cancel).

When I press an action button Im able to get an event on the app side, but i dont have any way to send the information fetch from the notification actions. The userInfo i receive here is the same i gave the notification.

Lets say I can selectable 5 options in the custom view.
What I'm attempting is to return to the app which buttons were selected on the custom notification when the action is pressed.

How can I give the information to the app of the button that was press on the custom view (view controller)?

the response on  "func didReceive" its a read only variable

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [IBAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton) attached to your specific button, then the next step would be placing your logic inside of said IBAction. Hope that documentation can help!

Comment: maybe i didnt explain well. A custom notification has a view controller that is drawn in the notification, then the notification itself has action buttons. The action buttons are defined as part of the notification, you have an object UNNotificationCategory which contains actions. On the other side... the VC has it own UIButtons. When you press an action button, you send an action with a static identifier (string) and thats all. I've not been able to find a way to attach extra information to this Action. When I get the action in the "observer" in the app all i have is the id (a static string)

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up by sharing some code from the main app with the custom notification. Now the notification has direct access to the service, which is something I don't really like but with the lack of time it was the solution I choose.

To do this choose the file from the project you want the notification to have access to, and on right side in the File Inspector -> Target Membership -> Select your notification

Be aware that all the functions used in this code need to be available from the notification project

Comment: turns out as i progress developing the app, that I still need information from the notification to be available in the app. The only way i see to make this happen is to send a notification to the server, and send back a silent notification.